# Error using FluentD fluent-plugin-sql plugin

Tags: sql-server, integration, extract, fluentd, td-agent

I am trying to use FluentD to get data from SQL Server via `fluent-plugin-sql`. I have installed tiny_tds and activerecord-sqlserver-adapter gems and my config looks like this:

```
<source>
@type sql
@id output_sql
host "sqlserverhost.aws_region.rds.amazonaws.com"
database db_name
adapter sqlserver
username user
password pwd
tag_prefix myrdb # optional, but recommended
select_interval 60s # optional
select_limit 500 # optional
state_file /var/run/fluentd/sql_state
<table>
    table tbl_name
    update_column insert_timestamp
</table>
</source>
<match **>
    @type stdout
</match>
```

when I restart `td-agent`, the service fails to start. Also, the logs don't indicate any error. I am not too sure what am I missing here. Any help in this regard will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Finally resolved this. Apparently the tzinfo gem's version was the issue. had to uninstall tzinfo's 2.0.2 version as it was causing conflict. For more details, refer to this [issue](https://github.com/fluent/fluent-plugin-sql/issues/87#issuecomment-614552292) for more context

Comment: Have you encrypted password which is in plain text in configuration